# Laravel scheduler run twiceDaily at specific hours

Tags: php, laravel, scheduler

How can I run Laravel scheduler twice daily at specific hours? Let's say I want my command to run every day at 9am and 5pm

There is an option to use twiceDaily, but I'm not sure how to specify hours

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use manual cron expression:

```
$schedule->command('foo')->cron('0 9,17 * * *');
```

Read more: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan#scheduling-artisan-commands

---

If you're not familiar with cron expressions, here's the nice GUI: http://cron.nmonitoring.com/cron-generator.html

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the `Schedulable` method then it would look like this:

`return $scheduler->twiceDaily(9, 17);`

Comment: This works fine, but how about 9am and 5:20pm?