# Laravel can dailyAt be nested?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Can dailyAt() be used in a nested way,

```
$schedule->command('foo')
         ->dailyAt('00:01')
         ->dailyAt('00:16');
```

Or it has to be like,

```
$schedule->command('foo')
         ->dailyAt('00:01');
$schedule->command('foo')
         ->dailyAt('00:16');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the manual cron expression like this:

```
$schedule->command('foo')->cron('0 9,17 * * *');
```

This was already answered on this question: [Laravel scheduler run twiceDaily at specific hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504359/laravel-scheduler-run-twicedaily-at-specific-hours)

Comment: but what about minute? like I need to run it at 00:01 and 00:16 . I need two cron entries for that?

Comment: In your case the cron would be `->cron('1,16 0 * * *');`

Comment: Thanks! @MarkDavidson